# filter data out of foreach loop show only parts of data

Tags: php, loops, foreach, filter

for my user manage system im making a set of radio option that fetches " groups"  from the database.

groups are for example admin, author, user and mod.

and it shows all groups fine

```
    <?php
    $groups = new User();
    $groups->getAllgroups();
    foreach ($groups->data() as $key=>$group) {
        echo '
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="grey" value="' . $group->id . '" name="group" id="group"';

        echo (escape($employees->data()->employee_group) == $group->id) ? 'checked' : ''; 
        echo '>' . $group->name . '</label>';
    }
    ?>
```

So it shows all the radio's attached to a group. But now I want to filter out admin (for example)

How can i do this the right way? So if ID is for eample 3 i dont want to show this, needs to get skipped

NOTE: Im struggeling with this textarea when i past in my code it gets messed up and whatever I do i can not get it right :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
foreach ($groups->data() as $key=>$group) {
    if($group->id != 3){
        echo '
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="grey" value="' . $group->id . '" name="group" id="group"';

        echo (escape($employees->data()->employee_group) == $group->id) ? 'checked' : ''; 
        echo '>' . $group->name . '</label>';
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I have tought about a simple if statement, but what if I also want to sort data like.. usergroups, modgroups, etc.. shoud this also be done with if statement,, then it would be a long statement.. I could do spereate sql statements to get seperate data but, im searching for a way to get something like a sorted array back...

Comment: @iZaaaa if you have other conditions that you want to check as well, do it in a separate function that returns a boolean and call it with the `if` condition, something like: `if(all_conditions_met()){...}`